# Multiple NativeScript Custom Components

Tags: xml, nativescript

I'm working with multiple custom components an everything works per the documentation.

***folder structure***

- app

  - pages

    - ...
  - custom

    - headers

      - header.xml
      - footer.xml
    - login

      - login.xml

***main-page.xml***

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" 
      xmlns:myHeaders="custom/headers" 
      xmlns:myLogin="custom/login">

  <StackLayout>
    <myHeaders:header />
    <myLogin:login />
    <myHeaders:footer />
  </StackLayout>

</Page>
```

This works producing the intended output on the screen.

Is this the best way to deal with custom components (mixing similar ones in a directory; creating new namespaces for other components) or is there a way to split those into their own directory and have them under a similar namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common pattern for structuring custom components in NativeScript projects.

Putting individual components in additional folders will require additional namespace references, as you suspected. NativeScript does not presently provide a way to create a shared namespace for custom components that live in different folders.

Comment: Thanks. Good to know.